# Use Watir to Select from Angular Non-Traditional DropDown

Tags: javascript, ruby, angular, watir

I am trying to select a drop down option from an angular `ng-select` list with Watir. I am not seeing the change made in the browser. I also am trying to 'click' on the drop down to open the drop down:

```
<div _ngcontent-c8="">
                <ng-select _ngcontent-c8="" bindlabel="SN" bindvalue="SN" class="custom-select ng-select ng-select-single ng-select-searchable ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-select-opened ng-select-bottom" formcontrolname="homeState" id="home-state" name="home-state" placeholder="Select Home State" role="listbox"><div class="ng-select-container ng-has-value">
    <div class="ng-value-container">
        <div class="ng-placeholder">Select Home State</div>

        <!----><!---->
            <!----><div class="ng-value">
                <!---->

                <!---->
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-value-icon left">×</span>
                    <span class="ng-value-label">AL</span>

            </div>


        <!---->

        <!----><div class="ng-input">
            <!---->
            <!----><input autocomplete="off" role="combobox" type="text" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="grwygr3432432" aria-activedescendant="a97e3c974a78">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!---->

    <!----><span class="ng-clear-wrapper" title="Clear all">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-clear">×</span>
    </span>

    <span class="ng-arrow-wrapper">
        <span class="ng-arrow"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<!----><div class="ng-overlay-container">
    <div class="ng-overlay"></div>
</div>

<!----><ng-dropdown-panel class="ng-dropdown-panel ng-select-bottom" id="grwygr3432432" style="opacity: 1;">
        <!---->
        <div class="ng-dropdown-panel-items scroll-host">
            <div></div>
            <div>


    <!---->
        <!----><div class="ng-option ng-option-marked" role="option" id="1">

            <!---->

            <!---->
                <span class="ng-option-label">AK        </span>

        </div><div class="ng-option" role="option" id="2">

            <!---->

            <!---->
                <span class="ng-option-label">AL        </span>

        </div><div class="ng-option" role="option" id="3">

            <!---->

            <!---->
                <span class="ng-option-label">AR        </span>

        </div><div class="ng-option" role="option" id="4">

            <!---->

            <!---->
                <span class="ng-option-label">AZ        </span>

        </div><div class="ng-option" role="option" id="5">

            <!---->

            <!---->

            <!---->
                <span class="ng-option-label">KY        </span>

        </div>
            <!rest of the states>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
    </ng-dropdown-panel>
</ng-select>
              </div>
```

In ruby when I do `@browser.select_list(id: 'home-state')` Watir says `UnknownObjectException`.

I'm thinking because instead of a traditional select list this is an angular ng-select with ng-dropdown-panel. How can I access this element and set values? As a sidenote, I did try using JS to set the `innerText` property to a state but when I saved the form this html resides on, the value for the state did not update.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use a select_list for elements that aren't actually standard html select/option element select lists. Treat the elements like any other element in Watir with div and span methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Watir is looking for an element type that is not present with the id you specified. I would suggest trying something more general, like this:

```
@browser.element(id: 'home-state')
```

More info can be found in the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/0.9.9/Watir/Element).

You might also have some luck with a library like [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize), where the solution would be something like:

```
require 'mechanize'

bot = Mechanize.new
page = bot.get('http://example.com')
list = page.css("#home-state").map.to_a.first
```

The caveat with Mechanize is that is doesn't handle Javascript. If you need something that will behave more like browser automation, stick with Watir (or something else Selenium based).

Comment: Watir is the wrapper around selenium.

Comment: It's not the only wrapper around Selenium. It's actually pretty far abstracted. If you wanted something that is much more like a barebones wrapper, you should check out https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver.

Comment: I am using watir for last 8 years. I am well aware of what watir IS!

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the tone/meaning of your comment. I see now that my original phrasing was possibly confusing-- I was suggesting to the original poster that they should stick with Watir or another Selenium-based library (indicating that Watir is also Selenium based) if they needed JS functionality.